# My code seems to enter an infinite loop after loading a list from a binary file

Tags: c++

I was studying the STL and decided to write some code to practice the writing and reading of files. The problem consists of creating a list of `int` (0, 1,...,9), save it in a binary file, and finally load it again.

There are 5 basic code blocks:
1. create list
2. present list
3. save list
4. load list
5. present list again

It seems simple and straightforward; however, the code seems to get in an infinite loop.

```
int main(){
    list<int> numbers;

    /////// Create list of 10 integers ///////
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        numbers.push_back(i);
    }

    /////// Present List ///////
    cout << "List created: [";

    list<int>::iterator it;
    for(it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); it++){
        if(*it != 9){
            cout << *it << ", ";
        }
        else{
            cout << *it;
        }
    }

    cout << "]" << endl;

    /////// Save list ///////
    string fileName = "test.bin";

    ofstream outputFile;

    outputFile.open(fileName, ios::binary);

    if(outputFile.is_open()){
        outputFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&numbers), sizeof(numbers));
        outputFile.close();

        cout << "List saved to file." << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Could not open file named " << fileName << endl;
    }

    /////// Load list ///////
    list<int> anotherList;
    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open(fileName, ios::binary);

    if(inputFile.is_open()){
        inputFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&anotherList), sizeof(anotherList));
        inputFile.close();

        cout << "List loaded from file." << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Could not open file named " << fileName << endl;
    }


    /////// Present List ///////
    cout << "List loaded: [";

    for(it = anotherList.begin(); it != anotherList.end(); it++){
        if(*it != 9){
            cout << *it << ", ";
        }
        else{
            cout << *it;
        }
    }

    cout << "]" << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The problem is in the "Load List" code block, since, if I comment it out, everything works fine.

Am I saving the object correctly? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<char *>(&numbers)` - yeah, that's not going to work with `std::list`, or with pretty much anything that deals with indirection, for example using pointers.

Comment: The "STL" is dead. It's now just the "Standard Library".

Comment: You'll want to learn what [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) does.

Comment: Just a very minor point: `std::vector` usually is more efficient than `std::list` – so unless you need some special features of the latter (e. g. iterators/pointers not invalidating on modifications), you might prefer the former one...

Comment: You should keep definitions as local as possible. Why that iterator outside the loop? If you just wanted a shorter line: `for(auto it = ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the flawed logic of `reinterpret_cast<char *>(&numbers)`. Why?

`std::list` manages its storage using pointers. It simply holds a pointer to a chain of elements consisting of some objects and a pointer to the next element. You cannot simply treat it like a sequence of bytes and expect it to maintain its functionality.

What you instead need to do is to loop over the elements and write them to the file one by one:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::fstream file{};
    file.open("data.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);

    std::list<int> ints{2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

    for (int i : ints) {
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i), sizeof(i));
    }

    file.flush();
    file.close();
    file.open("data.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

    ints.clear();

    std::cout << "Before reading the file, size of the list is: " << ints.size() << '\n';

    for (int i; file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i), sizeof(i)); ints.push_back(i));

    for (int i : ints) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

Clarification of the second `for` loop:

```
for (int i; file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i), sizeof(i)); ints.push_back(i));
```

- We declare a variable `i` since we need a place where we read the data. This one should be quite clear. We do not need to initialize `i`, since the condition of the loop will take care of that (although it would probably be a good practice to do it anyway).
- The condition part: `file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i), sizeof(i))`. This may seem tricky at first, but it really isn't! First of all, we have a method call. We call `std::basic_istream::read`, specifying the two arguments - first, the memory address where to read the variable, and second, the number of bytes we want to read. The trick is that the `read` method not only reads and saves the data - it also *returns the stream*, so essentially after the data processing, we are left with the condition `file`. But it's not a `bool`, is it? Correct, it's not a `bool` (neither an `int`), but stream objects *can be implicitly converted to `bool`*, which is exactly what happens here! The rules are as follows: if the stream is in a correct state, the conversion returns `true`. It returns `false` otherwise. An incorrect state may be cauased, for example, by failure to read, which happens, for example, when you already have read the whole file. Essentially, this part **both** *reads from the file* **and** *checks whether the reading process executed successfully*. It's both the reading logic and the condition!
- The third part: `ints.push_back(i)`. Notice that this part only executes if the condition (reading from the file) executed successfully. It simply adds the read `int` (`i`) to the `ints` container.

All in all, you can read the `for` loop in the following way:

- create a variable `i`, which will store, one by one, the variables from the file
- as long as reading from the file is successful...
- ...add the read value to the container

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was wondering if you could clarify the following line of code `for(int i; inputFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i), sizeof(i)); anotherList.push_back(i));`.

I've never seen this syntax before and I'm having trouble to understand it. Shouldn't the for loop have the following syntax `for(initialization; condition; increase) statement;`?

Comment: @eduardogfma I have added some explanations at the bottom of my answer. Good question, by the way :)

Comment: what a beautiful piece of code! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
outputFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&numbers), sizeof(numbers));
```

What you actually print is the binary representation of the list object itself. Unfortunately, it does not contain the data of the list directly, but instead looks similar to something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class list
{
    struct node
    {
        node* next;
        node* previous;
        T data;
    };
    node* m_head;
    node* m_tail;
    size_t m_size;
public:
    // ...
};
```

No direct link to the data. Even worse: With `std::list`, the data can get shattered all over your memory (in contrast to `std::vector` which assures contiguous data).

So you only can iterate over your list *again* (either with the iterator variant you chose already before or, more convenient, with a range based for loop):

```
for(auto n : numbers)
{
    outputFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n), sizeof(n));
}
```

Reading is different; you don't know the size in advance, do you? Well, there are ways to retrieve it ([`seekg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stream/seekg), [`tellg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg)), but that's more of interest if you want to read all the data into contiguous memory at once (you could [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) sufficient of in a `std::vector`), but that's another issue.

For the list approach:

```
int n;
while(inputFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n), sizeof(n)))
{
    anotherList.push_back(n);
}
```